# How to call functions from client side in room in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

How can I call below all function in specific room in socket I Sucessfully created room and joined it by connectToRoom function but now I want to call other function which I emited in sever side but i got only on message printed that "You are in room no 1"

`app.js`

```
 var app = require('express')();
 var http = require('http').Server(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);

 app.get('/', function(req, res) {
 res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
console.log('socket connected')

 const userId =  socket.id
 //  const emailId= await fetchemailId(socket); default room
 io.sockets.adapter.rooms
 socket.join(userId);

 //Send this event to everyone in the room.
 io.sockets.in("room-"+userId).emit('connectToRoom', "You are in room no. "+userId);
 io.to(userId).emit('Image upload');
 console.log(sockets.rooms)
 io.to(userId).emit('progress', "Image is Uploading started Please Wait A minute");
 io.to(userId).emit('error', "clients connected!");

});


http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

default room [reference](https://socket.io/docs/rooms/#Default-room)

`index.html`

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
     <title>Hello world</title>
 </head>
 <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

 <script>
   var socket = io();

    socket.on('connectToRoom', function (data) {
       document.body.innerHTML = '';
       document.write(data);

         socket.on('error', function (data) {
         document.body.innerHTML = '';
         document.write(data)
       });
         socket.on('progress', function (data) {
         document.body.innerHTML = '';
         document.write(data)
      });

 </script>

 <body></body>

 </html>
```

Comment: You can just call your functions but putting them under the event listener on the client side. So everytime when an event is fired from the backend to the frontend, the function under the frontend event listener will be called.

Comment: it means code is perfect

Comment: Isn't it? Does it not work? What's the error if that's the case?

Comment: I have Added both functions but it only shows me the room no in browaer not progress function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your all socket code I one function which I have mentioned below

Import `jquery`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

function

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
      //socket.io code
 });
```